# How to properly convert this working example to use ajax? (show details based on radio button selection)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a page to edit the administrators of a post.

In this page there are some radio buttons. Each radio button corresponds to a administrator of a post (ex: John, Jake, etc). When a radio button is selected the details of that administrator (name, email, etc) should be populated in the form fields. There is also a radio button "create new admin" that should reset the form fields when is selected.

I did this without ajax but now Im trying to replicate what I have but using ajax, that is, load each admin details and populate the form fields with that details, based on radio button selection, through an ajax request.

I have this ajax code in the view file but Im in doubt if its correct and how to, after get the administrators details, populate the form fields with the selected administrator/ selected radio button. Do you know how to do that?

**Ajax code in the view file:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("input[name='radiobutton']").click(function() {
                let id = $(this).attr("id");

                $.get('post/edit/'+ id+ '/admins', function(administrators) {

                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Below I have the Full working code example without Ajax:

**Form in the view file:**

```
<form method="post" class="clearfix" action="{{route('admins.update', ['id' => $post->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    @foreach($administrators as $admin)
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="{{$admin->id}}" value="{{$admin->id}}">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="">
              {{$admin->name}}
            </label>
          </div>
    @endforeach
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="create_administrator"
             value="option2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
          Create new administrator
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" required class="form-control" value="{{ $admin->name }}" name="name">
  </div>

  <!-- below I have more form fields like administrator name, email, etc -->

  <input type="submit" id="adminStoreButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create"/>
  <input type="submit" id="adminUpdateButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update"/>
  </form>
```

**JS to populate the form fields based on radio button (administrator) selection:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#adminStoreButton").hide();

        var admins = {!!  $admin !!}

        $("input[name='radiobutton']").click(function() {

            if($(this).attr("id") == "create_administrator"){
                $("#adminUpdateButton").hide();
                $("#adminStoreButton").show();
                $("#edit_administrator").attr('action', '{{route('admins.store', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');
            }
            else{
                $("#adminUpdateButton").show();
                $("#adminStoreButton").hide();
                $("#edit_administrator").attr('action', '{{route('admins.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');

            }

            let id = $(this).attr("id");
            let data = admins.find(e => e.id == id) || {
                name: "",
                email: "",
                ...
            };

            $("input[name='name']").val(data.name);
            $("input[name='email']").val(data.email);
           ...            
        });
    });
```

**Administrator controller edit method that returns the view with the edit administrators form above:**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $administrators = Administrator::where('post_id', $id)->get();

    return view('administrators.edit')
        ->with('post', $post)
        ->with('administrators', $administrators));
}
```

**edit and update routes**

```
Route::get('post/edit/{id}/admins',    [ 'uses' => 'AdminController@edit', 'as'=>'admins.edit']);
Route::post('post/update/{id}/admins', [ 'uses' => 'AdminController@update', 'as'=>'admins.update']);
```

**Administrator controller update method:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string',
          ...
        ]);

        $adminToUpdate = Administrator::find($request->radiobutton);

        $adminToUpdate->name = $request->name;
        ...

        $adminToUpdate->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: too many codes make the question difficult to analyze would be good if it is a bit compact anyway clarify what exactly you need and what current code did give output. anyway, where your setting the variable `var admins = {!!  $admin !!}` as I can see you're using `$admin` outside the loop
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup and scripts don't look clean also makes everything complicated so, I will tell you how to accomplish this in the best way step by step

1) create a form markup to be populated once queried via ajax

something like below

```
<form class="myForm" action="">
   <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
   <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
   ... and so on...
 <button class="actionButton" type"button" data-action="create">update</button>
</form>
```

2) you need a function to query the admin like below

```
function queryAdmin(id){
   $('.myForm')[0].reset();
   return $.post(queryEndPoint, {id: id}, function(response){
       $('.actionButton').attr('data-action', 'update');
       $('.myForm').find('input[name="firstname"]').val(response.firstname);
       $('.myForm').find('input[name="lastname"]').val(response.firstname);
       .... and so on ....
   });
}
```

3) now the for loop to get admin list

```
@foreach($administrators as $admin)
      <button class="adminButton btn" data-id="{{ $admin->id }}"></button>
@endforeach
```

4) now code to query admin when clicked button

```
$('.adminButton').click(function(){
    queryAdmin($(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

this will fill the form with admin details

5) now update/create form function

```
function updateOrCreate(endPoint){ 
    $('.updateMe').click(function(){
       $.post(endPoint, $('.myForm').serialize(), function(){
          alert('done');
       }).fail(function(){
          alert('something error occured !!!');
       });
    });
   }
```

6) update or create action

```
$('.actionButton').click(function(){
   if($(this).attr('data-action') == 'update')
      updateOrCreate(updateEndpoint);
   else
      updateOrCreate(createEndpoint);
});
```

now it will submit the form with update request once queried admin

now I hope rest you can do in this way best of luck